# Проблема со считыванием строк с текстового файла

Tags: c++

Возникла такая проблема. Есть уже заполненный данными текстовый файл. В каждой строке одно слово. Нужно прочитать с файла эти данные и на их основе создать объект. Перед тем, как передать значения с текстового файла в конструктор, я их заношу в переменные. Но почему то, в переменные сохраняются пустые строки и мусор, а не текст с файла. Не могу найти причину, почему так происходит.

```
string name, surname, patr, town, country, tel;
int day, month, year;//переменные, в которые хочу занести строки с файла, но которые после считывания хранят пустые строки и мусор 

string fileName = "data_file.txt";
fstream dataFile;//поток
vector<PhoneBook> data;  
int flag = 1;



dataFile.open(fileName, ios::out | ios::in);

if (flag == 1)
    {
        while (!dataFile.eof())
        {
            dataFile >> surname >> name >> patr >> day >> month >> year >> town >> country >> tel;
            data.push_back(PhoneBook(surname, name, patr, day, month, year, town, country, tel));
        }
    }
```

Текстовый файл:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1te5QG_C2yatooN2Mt9IpHrttGUXjZZGo

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: попробуйте `ifstream dataFile;`

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум замените

```
    while (!dataFile.eof())
    {
        dataFile >> surname >> name >> patr
                 >> day >> month >> year >> town >> country >> tel;
```

на

```
    while (dataFile >> surname >> name >> patr >> day 
                    >> month >> year >> town >> country >> tel) {
```

`eof()` говорит правду только **после неудачного чтения за концом файла**. Так что как минимум последняя запись может содержать что угодно...

Далее, вы вообще проверяли - открылся ли файл? Может, он вообще не открыт, а вы читаете мусор. Проверьте! Может, он только для чтения, а вы его хотите открывать и для записи тоже (`ios::out`). А может, он не там лежит...

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Проверки я все делал. Сейчас попробую убрать eof()